# Load balancing of tomcats is done, but still the application is slows?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, tomcat, load-balancing

I have 2 different *tomcat server* and using *apache* for load balancing.
I am using *SQL server 2005* as database. Database server has a RAM of 28 GB.
Both tomcats are communicating to same database.

As the no. of user increases during 12 PM to 4 PM, application usage goes up, the application slows down due to which the site is unable to come up fast.
On Saturday and Sunday as the users are very less. The application is fast.

I am unable to come up with, what could be the reason of the application to be slow.
and what could be the right solution to handle the slowing of application.

Comment: Load balancing does not make your application any faster, in fact there is some overhead. What load balance gives you is the ability to support a greater load and a degree of fault tolerance. So, load balancing will help if your problem was that your server was overloaded.

Answer (score 3):

And, of course, you investigated and discovered that it was the load on Tomcat that was causing the problem *before* you load balanced at that point, yes?

You need to find out where the bottleneck is (and we can't tell you that, at best we can make suggestions on where to look). Adding a thousand Tomcat servers won't help you if the problem actually lies in your database (as one example).

There are any number of things you can examine to assist. The logs for your application are one, to hopefully pinpoint where the delay is. Also, Apache itself maintains logs which can be invaluable for finding problems.

Similarly, trying one of the application queries from the command line when the database is under load may also tell you something.